# Get Edge's Vertex IN and OUT RID

Tags: orientdb

The following query produces what I want but it returns the @RID of the edges for IN and OUT. Is there any way I can convert them into the Vertex's IN and OUT?

```
SELECT FROM (
     TRAVERSE out('Child') FROM #21:0
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT @rid, name, in().name as in, out().name as out FROM (
     TRAVERSE out('Child') FROM #21:0
)
unwind in
```

this is what you get:

[image]

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thanks so much!